# Compare a Timestamp stored as varchar to a Timestamp in Java with JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, timestamp

we have a Timestamp-Column in an Oracle-Database which stores timestamps as a varchar2.
I want to create a query with the JPA CriteriaBuilder which compares the varchar2-Timestamps to a Timestamp-Object in Java. 
Unfortunately due to a bug in our Hibernate-Provider the `CriteriaBuilder.function()`-Method has a bug, therefore i am not able to use the Oracle-Database `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` function.

Hence i need another solution to get a comparable timestamp object out of the varchar2-timestamp. Is it possible to let Hibernate Cast the varchar2-Timestamps to Timestamp Objects in Java in order to do a comparison. E.g. like `cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo((Timestamp) get(varchar2-Timestamp)`, Java-Timestamp)?

Sorry, maybe the question is a little bit dump but i am very inexperienced in JPA and the offered possibilites.

Comment: Storing timestamps as varchars is a bad idea. But if the chosen format is wisely chosen (like yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss for example), then the chronological order and the lexicographic order are equivalent. So you can just transform the Java timestamp to a string, the same way you're doing to store it in the database, and compare the strings.

Comment: Is it possible to compare Strings in that way with the CriteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo() Method?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.